# MySQL trigger issue on insert

Tags: mysql, triggers, insert

I'm running an insert into a members table and when a new row is added I want to run a trigger to update the username field of the members table but it wont let me due to constraints due to possible deadlock situations.

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER tr_add_member
AFTER INSERT ON td_members
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
    IF mem_username = '' THEN
         SET mem_username = CONCAT('user' , mem_id);
    END IF;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

I've tried using the OLD and NEW keywords but they don't work, I've removed the NEW and OLD keywords above but get the below error with this trigger.

```
ERROR 1193 (HY000): Unknown system variable 'mem_username'
```

Should I be calling a procedure from the trigger to do what I want it and just run a simple `UPDATE` statement from within the procedure?

Comment: Are you trying to change the newly entered row?

Comment: @Ravinder, yes, I'm checking to see if the `mem_username` field is empty and if it is it takes the `mem_id` from the newly inserted row and prepends it with `user` so if the newly inserted row has an ID of 19 then mem_username would be set to `user19`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, but not an `AFTER INSERT`.

And if `mem_id` is auto incremented primary key field, then find its
next auto increment value from `information_schema.tables` and use it.

**Change your trigger code as follows**:

```
DELIMITER //

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS tr_add_member //

CREATE TRIGGER tr_add_member
       BEFORE INSERT ON td_members
       FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE _mem_id INT DEFAULT 0;

    IF length( trim( NEW.mem_username ) ) = 0 THEN
         SELECT AUTO_INCREMENT INTO _mem_id
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
          WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'td_members'
            AND TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE();

         SET NEW.mem_username = CONCAT( 'user', _mem_id );
    END IF;
END;

//

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: The trigger runs but adds in `user0` into the mem_username field when it should be `user1`, any suggestions?

Comment: It depends on your input for `mem_id`. How are you inputting its value?

Comment: `mem_id` is an auto_increment field, MySQL is looking after this value. So I expect the value doesn't exist when the trigger runs as it runs before the insert.