# Set max value as default value

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to store the order of the products in a database, and I want every new product added to be at the last position. Basically, I want the "rank" field to be set to MAX + 1, and MAX should be the highest value between the entries having the same "type".

I tried to do with a trigger, but since MySQL won't let me do that since the trigger would be executed on the same table :

**#1442 - Can't update table 'products' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger. **

Here is what my trigger was like :

```
CREATE TRIGGER `productInsert` 
AFTER INSERT ON `products` 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
   UPDATE products 
   SET rank = (SELECT MAX(rank) 
               from products 
               where type_id = NEW.type_id) 
   where id = NEW.id
```

Is there any other way to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a *before* insert trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `productInsert`
    BEFORE INSERT ON `products`
    FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    set NEW.rank = (select max(rank) + 1
                    from products p
                    where p.type_id = NEW.type_id
                   );
END
```

Comment: Let us hope `id` is not the auto incremented primary key field. Otherwise, the `NEW.id` has to be replaced by `auto_increment` value read from `information_schema.tables`. Example: [*Reading Auto_increment*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23962095/767881)

Comment: @Ravinder No problem, actually I use NEW.type_id instead of NEW.id, and type_id is not auto incremented.

Comment: @Ravinder . . . That was a typo in the statement.